# mpd cannot find music files on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, daemon, mpd

I have some music files in `~/Music`:

```
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~/.ncmpcpp$ ls ~/Music
Bastion Original Soundtrack     This War of Mine OST
Beholder OST                    Titan Souls Special Edition Content
Hyper Light Drifter soundtrack  Transistor Soundtrack
Stellaris soundtrack
```

After successfully doing `sudo apt install ncmpcpp mpd`, I tried to configure them.

> ~/.ncmpcpp/config

```
mpd_host = localhost
mpd_port = 6600
mpd_music_dir = ~/Music
```

> /etc/mpd.conf

```
music_directory                 "~/Music"
......
```

Then I launched the music player with `sudo service mpd restart && ncmpcpp`, but it seems that `mpd` cannot find my songs.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself: you should use

```
mpd_music_dir = "/home/sunqingyao/Music"
```

instead of

```
mpd_music_dir = /home/sunqingyao/Music
```

The quotation marks mustn't be omitted.